# How to variably extend classes in Java

Tags: java, events, event-handling

I'm trying to override the behavior of a lot of classes, all of which extend the same class.

Example class:

```
public void example extends Gui {
    public void draw() {
        //Draws some stuff
    }
    public void exit() {
        //Exits
    }
    private void handleMouseInput() {
        //Handles mouse input
    }
    public void handleKeyInput() {
        //Handles keyinput
    }
}
```

I have an event handler, every time a Gui is opened, the GUI is first passed through the event handler.
I would like to take the GUI, and override the handleKeyInput() method with my own code as they come through the event handler. All the GUI's coming through the event handler have the same methods.

I would like to create a method/class which takes a Gui as it's argument, and returns a new Gui with the handleKeyInput() modified. This way, I can create a universal key bindings which will work for all Gui's, without having to manually modify all of them one at a time.

i.e

```
public static Gui changeKeyInput(Gui guiToModify) {
    return guiToModify with handleKeyInput() modified;
}
```

A simple example (although impossible) is this:

```
public class randomGui extends variableA 
    Gui variableA;

    public randomGui(Gui variableA) {
        this.variableA = variableA;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleKeyInput() {
        //MyCustomCode
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you need to achieve? Regardless of what you have tried.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula I need to return the object given to me in the event handler arguments with one of it's methods modified.

Comment: I agree with @ThiagoPorciúncula: please tell us the details, because this question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) in disguise. Also, please avoid generalities such as by saying "with one of its methods modified" -- instead please try to be specific: what **exactly** does it do now, and what does it need to do.

Comment: On a basic level, a bunch of GUI stuff get's passed through this event handler, currently they have keyEvents which are fired when a key is pressed. I need to add a keybind which will fire on ALL GUI's, therefore I need to override the method and add my own handling (since I also want to remove the existing keybind handling)

Comment: Are you talking about Bukkit API's inventory events? Then maybe it can be solved with the API itself. Please add the [tag:bukkit] tag and explain the problem in a more specific way.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to use a [Decorator Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), similar to what Java uses with InputStreams and OutputStreams -- where Java allows you to decorate InputStreams as BufferedInputStreams and the like, adding functionality as needed. You would pass your object into your decorator's constructor, and it should use the unchanged methods of the object via simple delegation, and would allow you to alter the method that you wish to change.

```
public class DecoratorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyDecorator myDecorator = new FirstClass();
        testDecorator(myDecorator);

        System.out.println();
        myDecorator = new SecondClass(myDecorator);
        testDecorator(myDecorator);
    }

    private static void testDecorator(MyDecorator myDecorator) {
        myDecorator.stableMethod1();
        myDecorator.stableMethod2();
        myDecorator.changedMethod();
    }
}

interface MyDecorator {
    void stableMethod1();
    void stableMethod2();
    void changedMethod();
}

class FirstClass implements MyDecorator {

    @Override
    public void stableMethod1() {
        System.out.println("in stableMethod1 of FirstClass");
    }

    @Override
    public void stableMethod2() {
        System.out.println("in stableMethod2 of FirstClass");
    }

    @Override
    public void changedMethod() {
        System.out.println("in  changedMethod of FirstClass");
    }

}

class SecondClass implements MyDecorator {
    private MyDecorator loadedObj;

    public SecondClass(MyDecorator loadedObj) {
        this.loadedObj = loadedObj;
    }

    @Override
    public void stableMethod1() {
        loadedObj.stableMethod1();
    }

    @Override
    public void stableMethod2() {
        loadedObj.stableMethod1();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedMethod() {
        System.out.println("in  changedMethod of SecondClass");
    }

}
```

Note however if all you wish to do is to change Key Bindings, then this may not be needed, since you can remove and add Key Bindings to a JComponent without need of a decorator. The devil is in the details: the details of any solution will depend directly on the details of your problem.

Comment: I had tried something like this, however I run into issues with the delegation... Since not all the methods are public, the decorated object had limited capabilities and/or crashed.

Comment: @Storm-: Please edit your question and provide the necessary details.

Comment: As a side note, these are not Swing gui's. ;P

Comment: @Storm-: that's not a side note, but key information. Please edit your OP, telling us what GUI library you're using, and adding the appropriate tag.

Comment: It's Minecraft's private Gui system, it's not really a library but a protected series of classes which I'm trying to modify. I didn't mention the fact that it was a GUI to start with because I realized it was useless information.